# new to android - how to place button right on top of view

Tags: android

i have a button which shows an image:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/calendarheader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/calendar"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_days" />
```

I want to place it on top of this:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp" >
</GridView>
```

I tried to physically move it by pointing and clicking, but it just snaps back to some other position...

can u help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want it right then :

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

and top

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

and you can add margin Right and Top as you like

and change grid instead of 
`this android:layout_above="@+id/tableRow1"` 
to
 `android:layout_below="@+id/calendarheader"`

This will make your button on top right of its parent and below it your grid

*Full Code:*

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calendarheader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_days" />

   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calendarheader"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp" >
  </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add:

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
```

to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calendarheader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/calendar"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_days" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp" >
</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```